# Software to compute spherical harmonics in higher than 3 dimensions (100 or maybe 500 dimensions)?

Tags: special-functions, spherical-harmonics

I have been trying to find an implementation of Spherical harmonics for higher dimensional data but I couldnt find anything in Sage, Mathematica, Matlab. Does anyone have any idea of a standard/fast implementation ?

**MORE DETAILS**: I am adding more information about the expression that I am interested in. This comes from equation 13 from this [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1790-regularization-with-dot-product-kernels.pdf) on the eigenfunctions of dot product kernels.

> Moreover, the Legendre Polynomials may be expanded into an orthonormal basis
>   of spherical harmonics $Y^d_{n,j}$ by the Funk-Hecke equation to obtain: 
>   $$P^n_d(x.y) = \frac{|S_{d-1}|}{N(d,n)} \sum_{j=1}^{N(d,n)} Y_{n,j}^d(x) Y_{n,j}^d(y)$$

Here $x,y$ are vectors in $R^d$ with unit norm and I am interested in computing the spherical harmonic $Y_{n,j}^d$ at the points $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What kind of quantities do you want to compute? Values of spherical harmonics at points on the sphere? Dimensions of spaces of spherical harmonics?

Comment: @Neal : Thanks for the comment, I have added more details to the question.

Comment: I checked some of the libraries I have used in the past for computing SH, but found none that has support for this. The problem is that it's very unusual to use more than $3$ dimensions in any real-world applications so you would have to be a bit lucky to find a library where someone has bothered adding support for more than 3D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work for you?

> The [HFT.m Mathematica software package](http://axler.net/HFT_Math.html) performs symbolic manipulation of expressions that arise in the study of harmonic functions. This software, which is available electronically without charge, can perform symbolic calculations that would take a prohibitive amount of time if done without a computer. For example, the Poisson integral of any polynomial can be computed exactly.
>
> Some of the capabilities of this software:
>
> - symbolic calculus in $\mathbb{R}^n$
> - Dirichlet problem for balls, quadratic regions, annular regions, and exteriors of balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$
> - Neumann problem for balls and exteriors of balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$
> - biDirichlet problem for balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$
> - the Bergman projection problem for balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$
> - $\color{red}{\text{finding bases for spherical harmonics in }\mathbb{R}^n}$
> - explicit formulas for zonal harmonics in $\mathbb{R}^n$
> - manipulations with the Kelvin transform
> - Schwarz functions for balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$
> - harmonic conjugation in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Hope it's ok, I took the liberty of adding some text to your answer (otherwise I will likely get deleted ref. the comment above).